# How to have some area rendered below records in a AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex

In the AdvancedDataGrid shown bellow I have one groupingField as one can see.

I would like to have the ability to click in a record (let´s say the 26/01/2011 - Pag.) and right bellow it to have some action buttons.

How can I do it? Would it be by using a AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider? I´ve tried to do it but didn´t get the expected result.

[image]

Comment: Did this end up working for you?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to define your own ItemRenderer with states for normal/clicked

Example:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Keyword" dataField="keyword">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" 
                   click="this.currentState = (this.currentState=='normal')? 'clicked' : 'normal'">
                    <mx:states>
                            <s:State name="normal"/>
                            <s:State name="clicked" />
                    </mx:states>
                    <s:Label text="text" />
                    <s:Button label="Button" includeIn="clicked" />
                </mx:VBox>                      
            </fx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

When the user clicks the cell, the component will change states and render some buttons. You may have to call invalidateSize() on the datagrid to redraw rows.


From here you can do some research into rolling your own item renderers and how to access outside data. This should get your started. Hope it helps!